# What are some ways I can structure this Semi-Structured dataframe from ndjson format?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests, ndjson

(This is not real data)

I requested similar data from a Rest API. Then, I was able to convert some of the data to a .ndJSON format ( lines = True ); however, the address column is still shown in the ndjson format structure similar to a Python dictionary. My goal is to have the following columns:
Column 1
| Street Address | City | State | Postal Code | Zip Code | Birthdate |

This is the first row:

& address                                                                                            & birthDate  & deceasedBoolean &  \
0 & {[}{'city': 'MURFREESBORO', 'line': {[}'9999 Candy Cane Island'{]},   'postalCode': '39999', 'state': '56'}{]} & 11/10/2081   & 0 &  \

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from io import StringIO

data = response.text

newdf = pd.read_json(StringIO(data),lines = True)

newdf.tail(10)

newdf.to_csv('file.csv')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': [{'city': 'MURFREESBORO', 'line': ['9999 Candy Cane Island'], 'postalCode': '39999', 'state': '56'}], 
                               'birthdate': ['11/20/1977']})
# remove the [] from our address colum
df['address'] = df['address'].apply(str).str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '')
# turn string dict to dict
df['address']= df['address'].map(eval)
# explode the dict into multiple cols
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['address'].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
# join other col(s) 
df3 = df2.join(df['birthdate'])
```

output df

```
    city            line                   postalCode   state   birthdate
0   MURFREESBORO    9999 Candy Cane Island  39999        56    11/20/1977
```

Comment: I tried that and I got the following error: 
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: If you can copy and paste some of your actual data it will help a lot. It's hard to replicate your exact data structure from a screenshot.

Comment: address
[{'city': 'MURFREESBORO', 'line': ['9999 Candy Cane Island'], 'postalCode': '39999', 'state': '56'}]

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but I am not able to recreate the .str accessor error on my machine. I recommend using `newdf.to_dict()` and pasting the printed output into your question as an edit to make sure we're working with the same data. Additionally, you might have success with `df['address'] = df['address'].apply(str).str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '')` instead.

Comment: Hi Matt, I think the reason why I am not getting that  answer is because my data does not have a string around the [{ }]. It just looks like this [{'city':'NYC' and not this "[{'city':'NYC'. The first character is not ".

Comment: I edited my answer to match your quote format. I also changed this line `df['address'] = df['address'].apply(str).str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '')` to account for your Can only use .str accessor with string values error and the code above is working for me.